# What is the user-experience best practice for an alternative to popup windows?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, user-experience

I'm still new to web design/development. I'm working on a data entry form for an internal system at work. On the form, the user can select an office from a list queried from a database. (The backend for this is PHP and MySQL, if you're curious.)

I would like to add the functionality to allow the user to add an office to the list, among other things, with minimal invasiveness. I don't want to use a popup window since the default behavior for company browsers is to block popups. I've seen [this](http://www.willmaster.com/library/features/alert-box-alternative.php), which shows you how to create an alert alternative in place of a new window. To me that seems like basically the same thing, and not really an improvement except that it would keep the browser from putting a kibosh on the new form.

I think it might also be good just to keep the popup/alert functionality out of the picture altogether and opt for a new undisplayed `<div>` that is triggered by a button or doubleclick, autc. and closed by okay or cancel.

Like I said, I'm still new to web design/development, and I'm wondering what the currently accepted best practice is for accomplishing this task with the best possible user experience.

Update: the real question is "Is there a current best practice for accomplishing this task with the best possible user experience?" The answer may be "no, there are many options and none are more prevalent." What I'm looking for is either that, or "yes, the currently accepted best practice for user-experience in this case is X."

Comment: "I think it might also be good just to keep the popup/alert functionality out of the picture altogether and opt for a new undisplayed <div> that is triggered by a button or doubleclick, autc. and closed by okay or cancel."

This is exactly what the sample you linked to does. Uses a div in lieu of a popup.

Comment: Maybe a javascript/ajax form that allows for seamlessly adding offices without reloading the page?

Comment: @MikeBrown, it uses a `<div>` but it still has the ultimate effect of popping up with a window of some sort (an alert in this case) rather than some other design that might be better. I'm trying to ask what design choice would be better than a popup.

Comment: @Anonymous, thanks... I should have said that I feel that's a given in this case, at least when it comes to repopulating the select after the new office is added to the database.

Comment: If you can describe the task in more detail, and possibly provide a a screenshot or mockup, you'll get some good advice on the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: @tjb1982 no it doesn't popup a new window. it exposes the div inline, he just called it alert. did you try the sample at the end of the article?

Comment: @MikeBrown: I see what you're saying. My point is it's made to look like an alert. I'm sorry if I'm being confusing. I'm not looking for a way to duplicate what that guy did. I have a requirement to be able to choose or add an office, and I'm looking for the current best practice for doing it with minimal invasiveness. From the responses and my research, it's looking like there isn't one.

Comment: Hi tjb1982, this is off-topic here, but you can ask a new question on UX based on Patrick McElhaney's guidance and you'll get some great answers over there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cliche answer for "how do I do this with Javascript" is always jQuery.  I'm immensely happy with its `.dialog` call:

```
<div id="popup"><!-- all your markup for the dialog goes here --></div>

$("#popup").dialog ({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        "Ok" : function() { alert("ok was clicked"); }
        "Cancel" : function() { alert("cancel was clicked"); $(this).dialog("close"); }
    },
    modal: true
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* possibilities here:
You could for example:
* use fancybox, for popup-like looking functionality
* when user clicks 'add' you could load a new form, inject it to current page, and scroll to it.
* etc

What I personally would do, is look at the site as it is now. Is similar functionality already present? Can you use it? Does your new solution fit into the current gui?

Even the most usable solution will look bad, if it does not fit with the rest of the site. Your users are familiar with the current gui, if you add something new, you will force them to learn a new thing (that will take a lot of time, and you will get many 'bugreports' about it).

Answer (score 0):

> On the form, the user can select an office from a list queried from a
>   database

Just use a Combo Box.

Comment: Did you read beyond the first paragraph? "I would like to add the functionality to allow the user to add an office to the list". That's what the pop up is for, not the basic selection.

Comment: A Combo Box is CALLED a combo Box because it allows for Selection or free text entry....

Comment: I don't think there's really a VB-style combobox option in HTML. I think that's what you're referring to--if there were an easy/straight-forward way to implement that in HTML, that would be perfect. I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @tjb1982 - there are many ways to do this... Google it.